# How to differentiate $y = \sqrt{1-f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am in highschool, so forgive me if this question is considered too easy, but I was having trouble understanding how to tackle this question.

Would I re-write it as in terms of $f(x)$ or perhaps use $\frac{dy}{dx}$ notation?

Comment: Use chain rule :) , $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-f'(x)}{2\sqrt{1-f(x)}}$

Comment: Your question is not at all too easy. Two things you might want to do for further questions: (1) Explain what you've tried already, or what techniques you think might apply ("I think this is a chain rule problem,  but I don't see what $f$ and $g$ are in this case..."), and (2) let us know whether you want the whole solution, or just a nudge in the right direction ("Please don't give the whole answer -- I just want a hint to push me in the right direction".)

Answer (score 2):

Use the chain rule: $$\frac d{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$ (the notation doesn't really matter; use whichever is more convenient). With this in mind, the derivative of $\sqrt x$ is $\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$ and the derivative of $1-f(x)$ is $-f'(x)$, so the derivative of $\sqrt{1-f(x)}$ is $$\frac{-f'(x)}{2\sqrt{1-f(x)}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $y = (1 - f(x) ) ^ \frac{1}{2}$.

Now you already know how to differentiate

$$
z = u ^ \frac{1}{2}
$$
right? You get

$$
\frac{dz}{du} = \frac{1}{2} u^  {-\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

If $u$ is a function of $x$, then

$$
\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} u^  {-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{du}{dx}
$$
by the chain rule.

Now apply this to the case where $u = 1 - f(x)$. To do this, you have to assume that $f$ itself has a derivative, which might not be true, but your teacher probably wants you to assume it is.